# AirPlay menu incorrectly displays in portrait on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, avfoundation, avplayer, mpvolumeview

I'm using an AVPlayer and MKVolumeView to display the native AirPlay output menu.

In iOS 6, the AirPlay output menu seem to be presented in portrait regardless of the orientation of the status bar. In iOS 5, it followed the status bar orientation.

Any way to get it to follow the status bar, or at least force the orientation?

Comment: Set the orientation to whatever you want it to be in the Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to resolve this issue. Just override the UIActionSheet method showInView using a category. Then set the view in showInView with your view. Probably this will resolve the issue. It has worked for me.

Comment: I guess in the iOS 5 with mpvolumeview we have the action sheet orientable, but when it comes to the iOS 6 they have changed some modifications with the action sheet for airplay. The name of the action sheet which pops up when we press airplay button is the 'MPAudioVideoRoutingActionSheet'.

Comment: I guess that is the best one can do - even though it certainly carries the risk of getting rejected. From my experience however, modifications on MPMoviePlayerController and its interface are hitting a blind spot on the review team - they usually (never for me) do not care and approve such solutions (as they most likely did not check for them properly).

Answer (score 0):

**Note** The following misses the point and is only kept for reference - I will update this answer once I got some proper help from the apple engineers on this exact issue.

<strike>I had some luck using the following, adventurous pattern;</strike>

1. Create an intermediate viewController's with all orientations allowed.
2. That viewcontroller's view is entirely transparent (`UIColor clearColor` - **not** alpha = 0.0f).
3. Add that viewcontroller's view on top of the current view (`addSubview`).
4. Present the `MPVolumeView` from that intermediate viewController, on top of its entirely transparent view.

After sending in a TSI, the Apple dude asked me to submit a bug report -> tough luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but it made no difference. Did you get this to work? What do you mean by "Present the MPVolumeView"? I added the MPVolumeView to the view controller's view.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist you are right. I had used that pattern in conjunction with other stuff that was to be displayed on top of `MPMoviePlayerController`. When trying exactly what you are asking for, I noticed that my approach does not make any difference. I am very sorry to have sent you into this unhelpful direction.

Comment: That's no problem. So, did you find any other solution?

Comment: So far, no luck - I did check the apple forums and found this unanswered question: https://devforums.apple.com/message/745029 - will now use one of my TSI's to get an answer from Apple.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist TSI used, awaiting answer from Apple -> will keep you posted.